# ACH File Transmission

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, online-banking, ach

Is there any desktop software, either web based or desktop based, to transmit ACH File request to the financial institution? I saw some ACH File creation applications but cannot find any transmission/uploading software. I need it because of not knowing how to transmit this file. Already contacted departments like IT, Technical, Treasury but did not help.

Comment: "departments like IT, Technical, Treasury" so this is a task for your job?  Does your company work with a bank that can help you?

Comment: no, its for personal need.

Answer (score 1):

If it were possible to simply submit ACH requests directly as a private citizen, the banking system would likely have failed within a few weeks (if not hours) of making that directly possible.

The way the ACH system works, there's very little authentication that the request is legitimate; most of the authentication is that the *requestor* is legitimate, instead.  In particular, ACH supports [direct debit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_debit#United_States), which means that a biller can effectively withdraw money from your bank account without any direct action on your part for that particular transaction; as such, the ACH system relies on the fact that the system can trust its members to act honestly, based on financial penalties for not doing so, and the fact that they know who their members are (more or less).  Direct access by any relatively unknown private citizen would mean instant and massive fraud.

As such, you would have to use an indirect means. Venmo, Paypal, and many other third-party money transfer services use ACH, and so would allow you to create ACH requests within the limits of these platforms.  Further, your own bank likely offers you the ability to create ACH drafts through its online billpay mechanism, if the payee is in the system.  Some banks offer person-to-person payments as well, which in most cases use ACH.

Comment: JOE thank you for reply. I am not interested at your third paragraph but I am at your second one. Therefore obvious question is: How and where can I become a "member" of that ACH system?

Comment: Start a bank??  Not a personal finance question.

Comment: Joe, just FYI, the problems you are describing are specific to the US banking system. In other countries you can submit ACH batch files (of course you have to authenticate yourself), and it works fine. Yes the question is about US, I know.